# Mongo DB compare two arrays and add missing element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a statuses array as given below.

```
"statuses" : [
        {
            "name" : "In Progress",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2020-04-20T19:00:07.681Z")
        },
        {
            "name" : "Pending",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2020-04-20T19:00:07.886Z")
        },
        {
            "name" : "Viewed",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2020-04-20T20:10:04.733Z")
        },
        {
            "name" : "Initial Viewed",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2020-04-20T20:10:08.468Z")
        },
        {
            "name" : "Opened",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2020-04-21T01:37:08.582Z")
        },
        {
            "name" : "Completed",
            "created_on" : ISODate("2020-04-21T01:48:46.007Z")
        }
    ]
```

I have another array with which:

```
"reference": ['In Progress', 'Pending', 'Sent', 'Initial Viewed', 'Viewed', 'Opened', 'Completed']
```

As it can be seen when I compare my first array with reference array, 'Sent' is missing in first array which I would like to add in my first array with current ISODate(). And also I want my first array to be in the same order as the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) on `reference` you will get desired order. [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) along with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) will let you find single matching element and [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) can be used to build new object when there's no match:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$reference",
                    as: "ref",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                matched: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$statuses", cond: { $eq: [ "$$ref", "$$this.name" ] } } }, 0 ]
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $ifNull: [ "$$matched", { name: "$$ref", created_on: new Date() } ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZqZwI6Kvpm4)